# how can i add extra parameter to edit post link?

Tags: post-editor

i'm just reseach wordpress for few days. But i don't know what keyword to reseach this problem:

I have 2 post module called hotel and room . In hotel page when i edit , it have a button to redirect to add new room in room module . this link is :

```
example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post_type=room&hotel_id=30
```

But when i edit a room , this link is:

```
example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=31&action=edit
```

HOw can i add extra parameter to room edit to seperate which is room edit , which is hotel edit . Example:

```
example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=30&action=edit   (hotel)
example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=31&hotel_id=30&action=edit (room)
```

Can anyone give me a solution or keyword to research . Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_edit_post_link` filter lets you modify that value. This is applied any time `get_edit_post_link` function is called, which admin uses, as well as themes on the front end.

```
function wpd_edit_post_link_filter( $link, $post_ID, $context ){
    if( 'room' == get_post_type( $post_ID ) ){
        $link = $link . '&fubar=baz';
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'get_edit_post_link', 'wpd_edit_post_link_filter', 10, 3 );
```

You can use the `$post_ID` to fetch info about that particular post, and [`get_current_screen`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) might be helpful to decide when to apply the filter.